# Time controls in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm building my `Main()` method for a game I am developing in Eclipse, and I wanted to know if there are any time related classes already created in the Android SDK.

What I wanted to do was to make my `Main()` method loop through a `While` loop then wait 100 milliseconds, then loop again. I just need to know how I could make the loop wait.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.  You can read more about the Java timer API [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

```
import java.util.Timer;

...

int delay = 0;   // initial delay
int period = 100;  // repeat every 100 ms

new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            // Your while loop goes here
        }
    }, delay, period);
```